# Is there a way to have all radion buttons be unchecked

Tags: qt

I have a QGroupBox with a couple of QRadioButtons inside of it and in certain cases I want all radio buttons to be unchecked.  Seems that this is not possible when a selection has been made.  Do you know of a way I could do this or should I add a hidden radiobutton and check that onen to get the desired result.

Comment: This goes against the principle of radio buttons. By definition, exactly one is selected, always. Why do you need this?

Comment: @Thomas: It usually goes against the definition of radio buttons, but can be useful at times.  Consider a wizard where the user _must_ make a mutually-exclusive choice.  You can present them with radio buttons, but have no default.  Now imagine they back up to a previous page and change something that means you need to reset the rest of the data, including setting the radio buttons to nothing selected again.  (Ideally, the wizard wouldn't be able to advance until one of the radio buttons is selected, either.)

Comment: That is exactly why I need this.

Comment: I need this since the app cycles through a list of items and I want each item to load with a fresh UI.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can achieve this effect by temporarily turning off auto exclusivity for all your radio buttons, unchecking them, and then turning them back on:

```
QRadioButton* rbutton1 = new QRadioButton("Option 1", parent);
// ... other code ...
rbutton1->setAutoExclusive(false);
rbutton1->setChecked(false);
rbutton1->setAutoExclusive(true);
```

You might want to look at using [QButtonGroup](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html) to keep things tidier, it'll let you turn exclusivity on and off for an entire group of buttons instead of iterating through them yourself:

```
// where rbuttons are QRadioButtons with appropriate parent widgets
// (QButtonGroup doesn't draw or layout anything, it's just a container class)
QButtonGroup* group = new QButtonGroup(parent);
group->addButton(rbutton1);
group->addButton(rbutton2);
group->addButton(rbutton3);

// ... other code ...

QAbstractButton* checked = group->checkedButton();
if (checked)
{
    group->setExclusive(false);
    checked->setChecked(false);
    group->setExclusive(true);
}
```

However, as the other answers have stated, you might want to consider using checkboxes instead, since radio buttons aren't really meant for this sort of thing.

Comment: This behaviour is still necessary if, instead of radio buttons, you are grouping a set of push buttons.

Comment: @richardwb when i do the checked->setChecked(false), the button which was selected is disappearing from the screen. How is it working for you?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using QGroupBox to group buttons, you can't use the setExclusive(false) function to uncheck the checked RadioButton. You can read about it in [QRadioButton](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qradiobutton.html) section of QT docs. So if you want to reset your buttons, you can try something like this:

```
QButtonGroup *buttonGroup = new QButtonGroup;
QRadioButton *radioButton1 = new QRadioButton("button1");
QRadioButton *radioButton2 = new QRadioButton("button2");
QRadioButton *radioButton3 = new QRadioButton("button3");

buttonGroup->addButton(radioButton1);
buttonGroup->addButton(radioButton2);
buttonGroup->addButton(radioButton3);

if(buttonGroup->checkedButton() != 0)
{
   // Disable the exclusive property of the Button Group
   buttonGroup->setExclusive(false);

   // Get the checked button and uncheck it
   buttonGroup->checkedButton()->setChecked(false);

   // Enable the exclusive property of the Button Group
   buttonGroup->setExclusive(true);
}
```

You can disable the exclusive property of the ButtonGroup to reset all the buttons associated with the ButtonGroup, then you can enable the Exclusive property so that multiple button checks won't be possible.