# When a value is true other values are set false

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on a Qt GUI Application that in one module has a row of buttons that are checkable, what I need is to know the efficient way to set other buttons to false when one of them is clicked (set checked = true)

I tried to search on Google and Stackexchange stacks, but I'm not sure I'm using the right keywords.
What I've so far and it's working, but I don't think it's the best way

```
if(button1 == true)
{
    button2 = false;
    button3 = false;
}
if(button2 == true)
{
    button1 = false;
    button3 = false;
}
```

This is pseudo-code of course, and the number of buttons is larger

Any pointers to this programming concept, because this isn't Qt issue as much as own understanding of the concept.

Thanks.

Comment: [`QButtonGroup`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qbuttongroup.html#details) is just for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to have all radion buttons be unchecked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731620/is-there-a-way-to-have-all-radion-buttons-be-unchecked)

Comment: `QButtonGroup` solves my problem, thanks for the hint! but what if it's a C\C++ application or any other language not necessarily using Qt, I'm sure this pattern is established and solved, if an application with number of boolean values and have to be sure only one is true at anytime

Comment: I think I elaborated this issue in my question, should I edit the question by not mentioning Qt, just arbitrary boolean values?

Comment: A naive attempt is to do something like `void set_button_true(button b) { allButtons.set_button_false; b.status = true; }`

Comment: Tried and worked! Good one @henrikgiesel!

Comment: Do you mean that at any given time only one button may equal true? If that's the case, you may keep track of the button that is currently true, and when another one is clicked, set this one to false, updating the "true button" variable. Saves you a lot of button flicks.